# Uploading images jQuery File-uploader - min size?

Tags: jquery

How to forbid uploading of images less 300px x 300px?

Script: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: i think this is much better and also has functions to check the size of the image: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: look for image resizing: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
<br><br>
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API<br>
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible with javascript. Use a server-side script for that, eg. [Php's getimagesize()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). Alternatively you could search for a flash uploader.

Problem with javascript is that it has nog access to files on your pc, flash has. Therefore you'd need to upload the image first, so your server-side script language can process the image file

Comment: well you can with javascript  using fileapi or loading directly the image to a canvas and getmeasurements (just an idea)

Comment: don't try to use that on a production site without proper fallback. Browsersupport is really limited atm; ie doesn't support it at all, safari only partial, for chrome and ff only the newer versions (alltough since a few months they upgrade automatically, which is a good thing). Furthermore; files will be loaded in your memory, possibly causing your browser to crash when uploading/reading large files. A lot of work to do before we can safely use it. For now, only experiment and have fun and use the oldschool methods.

Comment: btw; for restriction purposes the same story applies as with all client-side solutions; good for notifying your user, bad for safety. ALWAYS use a server-side double-check.

Comment: well take a look at the jquery file upload by blueimp on github   maybe it can be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do (I am assuming that your question related [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) )

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 9990000, //9.9MB
    minFileSize:99000, //99KB
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 100,
    previewMaxHeight: 100,
    previewCrop: true
})
```